# Cambiar datos de ID por nombre de usuario en una fila de una tabla

Tags: postgresql

Saludos Comunidad tengo el siguiente caso

Tengo una Tabla **usuarios**,  que tiene la información completa de cada usuario y una columna PK=id y otra que tiene el nombre de estos id

Tengo otra tabla **datos**, que dentro de esta tabla tengo tres columnas que son "usuario_1","usuario_2","usuario_3", en estas tres columnas los que tengo son los id de la tabla **usuarios**.

Como puedo montar un select en la tabla **datos** donde pueda en la columnas "usuario_1","usuario_2","usuario_3" el dato nombre de la tabla usuario según se relacione con cada id

Tratando de plantear mejor la pregunta como hago para cambiar los id de la tabla **datos** de las columnas usuario,1,2,3 por el respectivo nombre de la tabla **usuarios**

Aclaro que ya tengo definidas los contraints FK con las columnas, el problema es si trato de usar un join para cada columna postgres solo me  permite  realizar con una columna no con las tres, cuando intento ingresar las otras dos columna, me responde con el error de que la tabla usuario ya se menciona mas de una vez.

Si monto el join con una sola columna funciona perfecto, pero  si quiero mostrar las tres columnas no logro  que funcione.

Agradezco si alguien ya paso por estoy y tiene solución.

Answer (score 0):

Dado que tienes 3 FKs debes hacer 3 joins. Por ejemplo:

```
select
  u1.nombre as usuario_1,
  u2.nombre as usuario_2,
  u3.nombre as usuario_3
from datos d
left join usuarios u1 on u1.id = d.usuario_1
left join usuarios u2 on u2.id = d.usuario_2
left join usuarios u3 on u3.id = d.usuario_3
```

Nota: Dado que se necesita hacer 3 joins con la misma tabla, es necesario usar alias para cada instancia de la tabla. En este caso, el ejemplo usa `u1`, `u2` y `u3` para distintas *instancias* de la tabla `usuarios` en la consulta.